# How to use wildcards with Envoy

Tags: python, python-envoy

I'm trying to run this command through KennethReitz's Envoy package:

```
$ sqlite3 foo.db 'select * from sqlite_master'
```

I've tried this:

```
r = envoy.run("sqlite3 foo.db 'select * from sqlite_master'")
sqlite3: Error: too many options: "*"
```

and this:

```
r = envoy.run(['sqlite3', 'foo.db', 'select * from sqlite_master'])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'returncode'
```

additional quoting & escaping doesn't seem to help.  Any suggestions?

FYI: This is what I had to do for now:

```
cmd = "sqlite3 %(database)s 'select * from sqlite_master'" % locals()
os.system(cmd)
```

Note that this is a contrived example, and that most of the unix shell commands that I'd like to issue aren't just a simple select that could be easily done via SQLAlchemy.

Comment: The sqlite3 module is included in python's standard libraries.  http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html  You'd be able to access the data from the db more directly that way.

Comment: Thanks - I agree, and am mostly using sqlalchemy.  But I also have to run quite a few shell commands that will require subprocess, os.system, popen, or envoy.  I'm hoping to confirm that Envoy will work for these simple commands.

Comment: you could write them as a single script and then spin them off with the multiprocessing module.

Comment: Yes, it would make it more difficult to generate the command.  I'd love some flexibility.   This isn't asking for much, and people frequently do exactly this with perl or python using popen, os.system(), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `subprocess`:

```
from subprocess import check_output as qx

output = qx(['sqlite3', 'foo.db', 'select * from sqlite_master'])
print output
```

Or `sqlite3` module:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('foo.db')
for row in conn.execute('select * from sqlite_master'):
    print row
```

If you still want to use `envoy` then you could fix it as:

```
import envoy

r = envoy.run([["sqlite3", "foo.db", "select * from sqlite_master"]])
print r.std_out
```

Comment: Thanks - the list within a list for envoy did the trick.  Can you tell me what's going on there?

Comment: @Buford Sweatley: I've just looked at the [source](https://github.com/kennethreitz/envoy/blob/master/envoy/core.py#L158). The original problem (string argument) seems like a bug in `envoy`.

Comment: This might be a silly question but I tried to "r = envoy.run('rm /tmp/*')" and it didn't work. r.std_error said: "No such file or directory" This was the only more or less related thread. Is this actually related?

Comment: @JoukeWaleson: `subprocess.check_call(['rm']+glob.glob('/tmp/*'))` or better: `for path in glob.iglob('/tmp/*'): os.remove(path)`. Note: both fail if `/tmp/` has subdirectories. I guess `envoy.run` doesn't invoke a shell by default so `rm` sees `/tmp/*` filename literally. You could [ask the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), somebody might provide more details.

Comment: Thanks, just did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722318/using-rm-wildcard-in-envoy-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 2):

This will not work in `envoy` because envoy splits the commands and pass them to subprocess. Even if you try with `subprocess.Popen(command, shell = False)` you will end up getting `sqlite3` terminal. Both `subprocess` and `envoy` fails to address this, I will be happy if you can open an issue in `envoy` since I am contributing to it, I will be thinking about this.