# Using rm * (wildcard) in envoy: No such file or directory

Tags: python, wildcard, rm, python-envoy

I'm using Python and Envoy. I need to delete all files in a directory. Apart from some files, the directory is empty. In a terminal this would be:

```
rm /tmp/my_silly_directory/*
```

Common sense dictates that in envoy, this translates into:

```
r = envoy.run('rm /tmp/my_silly_directory/*')
```

However:

```
r.std_err -> "rm: cannot remove `/tmp/my_silly_directory/*': No such file or directory"
```

Naturally there are alternatives to using envoy in this case, I am simply wondering why it doesn't work.

Any clues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On UNIX, it's up to the shell to interpret wildcards like `*`. If you execute a program and pass an argument with `*` in it directly to the program -- which is presumably what's being done here -- then you'll get an error like you're seeing. `rm` just assumes the `*` is a file name, and indeed, it's actually possible to create such a file.

One solution could be to execute the shell and let it execute your command on your behalf, something like

```
r = envoy.run('sh -c "rm /tmp/my_silly_directory/*"')
```

The shell will interpret the `*` before invoking `rm`.

Comment: This sounds perfectly right, and would probably work with subprocess. However, in envoy, the only call that works is `envoy.run([["sh", "-c", "rm /tmp/my_silly_directory/*"]])` for some reason. So much for a simpler `subprocess` ;)

Comment: couldn't get this to work with subprocess, by the way. Same error as original question.

Comment: @Nate: [`shutil.rmtree('/tmp/my_silly_directory/')`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106350/how-to-use-wildcards-with-envoy?lq=1#comment15551439_9109127)